highlight only cells above and to the left of active cell
I am currently highlighting the entire row and column of my worksheet.  I'd like to only highlight the cells to the left and above the active cell.
Current code is:
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
  'Clear the color of all cells
  Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
  With Target
    'Highlight row and column of the selected cell
    .Cells.Range.
   ' .EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(241, 227, 238)
    '.EntireColumn.Interior.Color = RGB(241, 227, 238)
    
    End With

End Sub

I know i need to change the .entirecolumn to a range of the first row down to the current row, and use that for the first part of my range, and then first column over to the current column for the second part of my range.
Range(ActiveCell.Column & ActiveCell.Row & ActiveCell.Column & "1").Interior.ColorIndex = vbyellow isn't working.  I am expecting this to highlight the current cell up to the top row.  Once i have this figured out, the highlighting of the row should be easy to figure out.

I am not sure what exactly you want to do, so I played around a little bit and prepared 6 different variations.

For the test, I read from cell F2 which variation you want to see:
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  
    Dim WhatDoYouWant As Long
    WhatDoYouWant = Range("F2")
    If WhatDoYouWant < 1 Or WhatDoYouWant > 6 Then WhatDoYouWant = 1
    
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
    'Clear the color of all cells
    Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
      
    Dim delta
    If WhatDoYouWant = 1 Or WhatDoYouWant = 3 Or WhatDoYouWant = 5 Then
        If Target.row = 1 Or Target.Column = 1 Then Exit Sub
        delta = 1
    End If
    
    Dim r As Range
    If WhatDoYouWant = 1 Or WhatDoYouWant = 2 Then
        Set r = Range("A1").Resize(Target.row - delta, Target.Column - delta)
    End If
    
    If WhatDoYouWant = 3 Or WhatDoYouWant = 4 Then
        Set r = Union(Range("A1").Resize(1, Target.Column - delta).EntireColumn, _
                      Range("A1").Resize(Target.row - delta).EntireRow)
    End If
    
    If WhatDoYouWant = 5 Or WhatDoYouWant = 6 Then
        Set r = Union(Cells(Target.row, 1).Resize(, Target.Column - delta), _
                      Cells(1, Target.Column).Resize(Target.row - delta))
    End If
                  
    r.Interior.Color = RGB(241, 227, 238)
End Sub

Of course, if you know which variation you want, you can simplify your code. Just be aware that you need to check if you are not in row or column 1 for the variations 1, 3 and 5, because only cells above and to the left are marked and there is no cell above row 1 and no cell to the left of column 1.
Let's say you want version 6:
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Clear the color of all cells
    Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
      
    If Target.row = 1 Or Target.Column = 1 Then Exit Sub
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Union(Cells(Target.row, 1).Resize(, Target.Column), _
                      Cells(1, Target.Column).Resize(Target.row))
    r.Interior.Color = RGB(241, 227, 238)
End Sub


This is what i shrunk the code down to and it works.  Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
  
Dim delta
delta = 1
    
Dim r As Range
    
Set r = Union(Cells(Target.row, 1).Resize(, Target.Column), _
                  Cells(1, Target.Column).Resize(Target.row))
r.Interior.Color = RGB(241, 227, 238)

End Sub

If Target.row = 1 Or Target.Column = 1 Then Exit Sub seems unreasonable. It should be   And. The remained code should be corrected accordingly.

You can use offset() to determine orientation from Target:
    With Target
        Range(Cells(1, 1), .Offset(-1, -1)).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End With


Try this code:
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
  'Clear the color of all cells
  Me.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
  
  With Target
        Dim row As Long: row = .row
        Dim col As Long: col = .Column
        If .row > 1 Or .Column > 1 Then
            If col > 1 Then Me.Cells(row, 1).Resize(, col - 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            If row > 1 Then Me.Cells(1, col).Resize(row - 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If

  End With
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


